# Perl -two list matching elements

Tags: perl

I am trying to grab the list of the files jenkins has updated from last build and latest build and stored in a perl array.

Now i have list of files and folders in source code which are considered as sensitive in terms of changes like XXXX\yyy/*.*, XXX/TTTT/FFF.txt,...in FILE.TXT

i want that script should tell me if any these sensitive files was part of my changed files and if yes list its name so that we can double check with development team about is change before we trigger build .

How should i achieve this , and how to ,compare multiple files under one path form the changed path files .

have written below script ---which is called inside the jenkins with %workspace@ as argument

This is not giving any matching result.

```
use warnings;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

$url = `curl -s "http://localhost:8080/job/Rev-number/lastStableBuild/" | findstr   "started by"`;
$url =~ /([0-9]+)/;

system("cd $ARGV[1]");
@difffiles = `svn diff -r $1:HEAD --summarize`;
chomp @difffiles;
foreach $f (@difffiles) {
    $f = substr( $f, 8 );
    $f = "$f\n";
}

open FILE, '/path/to/file'
     or die "Can't open file: $!\n";

   @array = <FILE>;

  @isect = intersect( @difffiles,  @array );

print @isect;
```

Comment: Please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  And if you do file processing, include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) as well.  This will help you find lots of bugs on your own, and will also get one better reception to questions asked on SO.

Comment: Additionally, your pasted code contains syntax errors: `@b= OPEN ($d,>"INPUT.TXT");`.  You should fix those before asking a question as well.

Comment: i have rectified the syntax error in file- thx for reminding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to solve this issue using below perl script -

```
 sub Verifysensitivefileschanges()
  {
    $count1=0;
    @isect = intersect(@difffiles,@sensitive);
    #print "ISECT=@isect\n";
    foreach $t (@isect)
    {  
      if (@isect) {print "Matching element found -- $t\n"; $count1=1;}

    }
      return $count1; 
}

 sub Verifysensitivedirschanges()
 {
    $count2=0;
    foreach $g (@difffiles)
    {
      $dirs = dirname($g);
      $filename = basename($g);
       #print "$dirs\n";
      foreach $j (@array)
      {
         if( "$j" =~ /\Q$dirs/)
         {print "Sensitive path files changed under path $j and file name is  $filename\n";$count2=1;}
      }
   }
     return $count2;
```

}